# C# Get the type of a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

How can I get the type of the inner-most elements of a multidimensional array?

```
var qq = new int[2,3]{{1,2,3}, {1,2,4}};
var t = qq.GetType().ToString();//is "System.Int32[,]"
var t2 = ??; // should be "System.Int32"
```

I'd like to get the innermost element type regardless of the number of dimensions of the array (Rank).

Comment: Something along the lines of             var qq = new int[2,3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 4 } };
            var bounds = Enumerable.Range(0, qq.Rank).Select(r => qq.GetLowerBound(r)).ToArray();
            var fst = qq.GetValue(bounds);
 but its buggy and complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `GetElementType()`:

```
var t2 = qq.GetType().GetElementType().ToString();
```

Comment: +1 you may also want to check with [HasElementType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.haselementtype.aspx) first

Comment: Sweet. I thought the `Type` type may have something usable, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

When you found there's a lack of methods out of the box of what you need, you can always write your own extension methods.

```
public static Type GetEssenceType(this Type node) {
    for(Type head=node, next; ; node=next)
        if(null==(next=node.GetElementType()))
            return node!=head?node:null;
}
```

It returns the *inner-most element type*(which I called the ***essence type***) if the given type(named `node` in the code) was a type which *has element type*; otherwise, `null`.

---

**Edit:**

`Type` has a internal method does the similar thing:

```
internal virtual Type GetRootElementType()
{
    Type elementType = this;
    while (elementType.HasElementType)
    {
        elementType = elementType.GetElementType();
    }
    return elementType;
}
```

You can create a delegate or use it via reflection:

```
var bindingAttr=BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var method=typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetRootElementType", bindingAttr);
var rootElementType=(Type)method.Invoke(givenType, null);
```

Note that `GetRootElementType` returns the given type itself if it doesn't have element type.

Comment: +1 'cause it works. But I find such for loops (needlessly) hard to read. Same for C++-like LHS null comparisons.